# How can I obtain explicit focus via the 'for' attribute on p:focus?

Tags: primefaces, attributes, focus, explicit

According to the documentation, it should be possible to explicitly declare that a form input 
element component receives focus via the 'for' attribute.
In this case, the second visible and enabled input element rather than the first by default - 
so can someone please help me by explaining why the following doesn't work?

```
<h:form id="form4">
   <p:focus id="pick" for="input2" />   
   <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{messageManagedBean.message1}"/>
   <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{messageManagedBean.message2}"/>

   <p:commandButton value="Execute JSF Lifecycle - Invoke Action One" action="#{messageManagedBean.doSomeAction41}" ></p:commandButton>
   <p:commandButton value="Execute JSF Lifecycle - Invoke Action Two" 
action="#{messageManagedBean.doSomeAction42}" ></p:commandButton>   

   <p:messages for="input1" id="messages1" autoUpdate="true"/>
   <p:messages for="input2" id="messages2" autoUpdate="true"/>

</h:form>
```

Many thanks!

[PrimeFaces: 3.5.25
JavaServer Faces: 1.2
Java Servlet: 2.5
Server: Apache Tomcat 8.0.15]

Comment: Works for me in 6.0, however, the code is different in 3.5: `focus.findComponent(focus.getFor())` vs `SearchExpressionFacade.resolveComponent(context, focus, focus.getFor())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the source of the `p:focus` renderer, you will see (in case you set `for`) the component is resolved and a bit of JavaScript is [written](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/3_5/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/focus/FocusRenderer.java#L73):

```
writer.write("$(function(){");
writer.write("PrimeFaces.focus('" + clientId +"');");
writer.write("});");
```

Since it's not working for your software stack, you could omit `p:focus` and simply write the JavaScript yourself:

```
<h:form id="form4">
   <script>
       $(function(){ PrimeFaces.focus('form4:input2'); });
   </script>
   <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{messageManagedBean.message1}"/>
   <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{messageManagedBean.message2}"/>
   ...
</h:form>
```

Yes, this is a hack. If you can, upgrade your software stack. For me your XHTML is working.